# How to left-align centered text only if hits a line break?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I condition my text to become left-aligned if hits the end of its contained space and has to switch to the next line? Is there something inherent within CSS that can detect it, or does it have to be a JavaScript solution?

Here's the fiddle so you can see how it should behave: https://jsfiddle.net/fj4ddmey/2/

```css
.text.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.text.container.two {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="text container">
  <p>This is how short sentences should look</p>
</div>
<div class="text container">
  <p>This text should be left aligned because it hits a line break</p>
</div>
<div class="text container two">
  <p>This is how it should look, but it needs to be a fluid solution</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for would be to inspect each `p` to determine if the height of the element in the DOM is larger than the line height. It might need to be a JavaScript solution, unless there is a more powerful media query than I've worked with before.

Answer (score 3):

Use `flexbox` like that

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is how it should look, but it needs to be a fluid solution</p>
</div>
```

Here is [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/do20zzhj/)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `<p>` as inline block, so that `text-align:center` on the container will center the `<p>` tag first, rather than the text. And inline-block has the shrink-to-fit feature, means the width is determined by the content, and never goes beyond the container, with `text-align:left`, text inside will be left aligned when it wraps.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
.container p {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>This is how short sentences should look</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p>This text should be left aligned because it hits a line break</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why neither this nor the flexbox solution works for me.

Comment: Can you share a demo on jsfiddle? so I can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to determine the element height, and if its greater than one line, add a class to justify the text appropriately.

Something like this should work:

```
function countLines(e) {
  var elementHeight = e.innerHeight();
  var lineHeight = parseInt(e.css('line-height'));
  var lines = elementHeight / lineHeight;
  return(lines > 1);
}

$('p').each(function() {
    if(countLines($(this))) {
        $(this).addClass('two'); //class to left justify
    }
})
```

You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/fj4ddmey/1/